# CORS in Spring Security (Spring Boot 3)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-3

I am currently struggling with Spring Security in my Spring Boot 3 applications. It was working in Spring Boot 2 but not since I tried to upgrade to version 3.

My authentication seems to work properly and the stuff that needs to be authenticated works. However when I do a preflight (OPTIONS) check it still returns me a 401 error.

My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(c -> c.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(
                            AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/comments/**"), 
                            AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/requests/admin/**")
                        ).authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .exceptionHandling(r -> r.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(r -> r.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
                .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ;
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

I tried using a CorsConfigurationSource bean, but with no luck

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
    return source;
}
```

And changed the `.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())` to `.cors(c -> c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())))` in the SecutiryFilterChain.

A lot of links on the internet provide help on the issue but for SB2 instead of 3.

Comment: please show us your error in the webbrowser console and a screenshot of your response with headers in the browser.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet. The 1 answer is not a good answer, especially when you have lots of Controllers > 60.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i tried configuring CORS the same way you did, using `http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())` and `http.cors(c -> c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())` but both did not work.

however, this works for me

```
http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        return configuration;
    }));
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick for me :D

Comment: You are great dude! :) dealing with this around 3 hours :P

Comment: This way you are whitelisting every origin for your endpoints. Is there no way of adding logic to whitelist selected resource

Answer (score 1):

**Spring Boot 3.1.X** + Spring Security + JWT + Angular frontend for /api.

For anyone having problems with `CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()` not working, try manually register your `corsConfigurationSource()`

```
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
...
.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
...
}
```

I've spent few hours trying many outdated solutions, none worked and well... finally resolving this. Hope this will save you time.

Example of @Bean to start with:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and was ultimately unable to solve it with httpSecurity.config

I wound up taking `.cors()` out entirely, and put a `@CrossOrigin` annotation
on each controller class, e.g.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://myurl", allowCredentials = "true")
```

Note that I'm specifying an explicit URL here.
I'm not sure whether or not wildcards will work.

Comment: My application is open for everyone to use (it's an application for training purposes) so I do not know the origins of the user as they might use postman or other tools. Wildcards do not seem to work (When allowCredentials is true, allowedOrigins cannot contain the special value "*")

Comment: I did try it though with defined origin, but to no luck :(

Answer (score -2):

OPTIONS method should be allowed explicitly.
Try adding in `.authorizeHttpRequests`:

```
.requestMatchers(
        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/comments/**"),
        AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/requests/admin/**")
).permitAll()
```